# Understanding reference concept in Java

Tags: java, reference

My question is about how references work in Java. As far as I've understood by reading of  [JLS 4.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2) reference is a formal name allows to work with an object that reference points to. Consider the following code:

```
public class A{
    private int a = 0;

    void mutate(){
        a++;
    }
}

public void foo (A a){
    a.mutate();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    A a = new A(); //a is a reference to the object of type A
    foo(a);
}
```

Is the reference `a` which is local to the `main` function the same as a reference which is used within `foo` function? I mean would operator `==` return true if we applied it to these references as one's operands?

Comment: Integer is a *wrapper* class, its instances are *immutable*. Pick a *Mutable* class like `StringBuilder` to try this example.

Comment: I believe this question is more about scope than references... Why use a as both instance of A and its internal counter...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is the reference a which is local to the main function the same as a reference which is used within foo function?**

No, the *reference* is different, the *instance* to which both references point is the same.

```
pubic void foo (A a){
```

`a` here is a *copy* of the reference of `a` of `main()` (or any function that calls it). The reference will be on the *stack* for this method and is lost when the method returns (Stack unwinds)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    A a = new A(); //a is a reference to the object of type A  // A is a reference on the Stack and local to main().
    foo(a);
}
```

Comment: _No, the reference is different_ This's the key point I want to know. It would be perfect if you provide a normative reference from JLS.

Comment: Straighten out your capitalization. You're mixing type names and variable names. Also, the word "stack" should not be capitalized here.

Comment: This is not just a matter of proper English. The difference between mentioning `A` and `a` is significant in this case. I can edit your answer if you don't care to correct it.

Comment: @TheLostMind One quibble: A function accepts parameters, and a caller supplies arguments to fill those parameters.

Answer (score 5):

No, the reference `a` in `main()` is *not* the same as the parameter `a` in function `foo()`. All function arguments are passed by value in Java. Copying a reference (`main`'s `a`) when calling on `foo()` creates a new reference that points to the same referent (the object created in `main()` by the expression `new A()`).

You will often hear people say colloquially that two references are "the same," but what that really means is that the two references *point to the same object or referent*. The references themselves may sit in different registers or memory location, but their *value*—the object to which they refer—can be the same, just like pointers and references in other languages.

Comment: Agree with this one. If you know about C/C++ you and understand deep copy and shallow copy concept, you will get this much easier.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
 foo(a)
```

You are technically calling mutate(a) from within foo(a). but the stack reference is different i.e. the reference `a` used in foo() and the reference in main() is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the reference a which is local to the main function the same as a
>   reference which is used within foo function?

They point to the same memory address if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I do. But that implies the Java pass-by-reference, not by-value.

Comment: Java passes by value, not by reference. Its references can be copied, though, rendering two values indistinguishable.

Comment: No, java pass by-value, changing 'a' inside foo() does not implies on 'a' of the main method. But are a point that may confuses: the value that java pass is the reference to the instance object.